# R: aggregate with custom function and external parameter

Tags: r, aggregate

I have data like this:

```
club <- c("a", "b", "c", "d","d", "a")
all.scores.math <- c(1,2,5,3,4,4)
all.scores.english <- c(2,2,4,3,4,1)
data <- cbind(club, all.scores.math, all.scores.english)
data <- as.data.frame(data)
data$all.scores.math <- as.numeric(as.character(data$all.scores.math))
data$all.scores.english <- as.numeric(as.character(data$all.scores.english))
```

EDIT: I also have some external parameters.

```
score.math <- 5
score.english <- 6
```

And I have a custom function, which actually contains a very long algorithm. However, not to write a lot, here is the short version. It requires a specific column of the dataset:

```
getratio <- function(some.data, score.math, score.english){
 result1 <- sum(some.data$all.scores.math)/score.math
 result2 <- sum(some.data$all.scores.english)/score.english
 results.list<-list(result1, result2)
 return(results.list)
}
```

Just doing the "getratio"-function works:

```
getratio(data, score.math, score.english)
```

Now, I would like to do this "getratio" for each "club":

```
aggregate(all.scores.math ~ club, data, getratio)
```

How can I include my external parameters, score.math and score.english?

Comment: What are `score.math` and `score.english`?

Comment: @G5W, these are some external scores. They are not contained in the dataset, but enter the "getratio"-function as parameters.

Comment: I meant that we need their values for testing.  For example,  we cannot run your line of code `getratio(data, score.math, score.english)` and do not have values to feed into the `aggregate`.  Could you please prive some values for testing?

Comment: @G5W, my bad. Just added.

Comment: `lapply(split(data, data$club), function(i) getratio(i, score.math, score.english))`

Comment: @Sotos, thank you. This seems as closest to what I had in mind.